# build doLast not executing on multi module build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi module gradle build and I am trying to aggregate the jacoco reports, but I want it to happen when the build completes and I do not want to add it to the end of the gradle command in terminal.  Below is the snippet of how I configured the build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    do stuff...
}
task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport, group: 'Coverage reports') {
    configure...
}
task build {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
    doLast {
        jacocoRootReport
    }
}
```

If I put a simple println in the doLast it will print it, but if I put println's in the jacoco report task nothing is printed.
I have tried using build.finalizedBy as well and that results in the same lack of execution.  What am I doing incorrectly?
inside the subtask build.finalizedBy works fine but outside the subtask nothing seems to work.

*** EDIT ***
Here is the actual code for the root report.
I tried using build.finalizedBy but it fails in the root build.gradle it only works in the subprojects

```
task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport, group: 'Coverage reports') {
    println 'start'
    dependsOn = subprojects.test
    additionalSourceDirs = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.output)
    executionData = files(subprojects.jacocoTestReport.executionData)
    println 'reports'
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination "$rootDir/build/reports/coverage/coverge-index"
        xml.enabled = false
        csv.enabled = false
    }
    println 'onlyIf'
    onlyIf = {
        true
    }
    println 'doFirst'
    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
            it.exists()
        })
    }
}

task build {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
    doLast {
        jacocoRootReport
    }
}
```

Comment: the `doLast` block of your `build` task does nothing: you simply get the task `jacocoRootReport` reference but you do nothing with it, that why it's not executed. (it's equivalent to write `project.tasks.getByName('jacocoRootReport')`) . The right way would be to use `build.finalizedBy('jacocoRootReport')` as you mentioned, and it should work . can you provide the code of your `jacocoRootReport` task definition ?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the build task to a depends on rather than doLast.  This does what I want.
Please feel free to correct me if there is a better way to accomplish what I want.

```
task build {
    dependsOn tasks.jacocoRootReport
}
```

I tried using build.finalizedBy(jacocoRootReport) and got the following error:

> unknown property 'build' in root project